# what's the use of git checkout action in a cicd pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, devops, github-actions, cicd

I've found that in many CICD pipelines such as Azure DevOps pipeline or GitHub action, there is always a checkout branch action. for Azure DevOps pipeline example

```
  jobs: 
    - job: test
      displayName: Integration Test
      steps:
        - checkout: self
          lfs: true
    ...
```

for GitHub Action example

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # checkout the repo
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: Azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }} 
    ...
```

What's the use of those checkouts? To clean the branch for the CICD pipeline?

Comment: You can have a look at the documentation of this action: https://github.com/actions/checkout.

When you set a checkout step without specifying any repo, you checkout the code of the current repo, so you can access files of this repo from your workflow.

You can also check out another repo by specifying **repository** param in **with** map

Comment: The thing that triggers a pipeline may not have anything to do with what to check out. And you may need to run a few things prior to getting the code. Adding the checkout step explicitly explains *what* will be checked out and *when* in your flow it's checked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CI/CD pipeline on GitHub or anywhere else, runs on a special machine called runner. For example, in case of GitHub, runner is a virtual machine hosted by GitHub with the GitHub Actions runner application installed. The ultimate goal of any CI/CD pipeline is to run some commands on the files of your repository. So how does this new machine have the codes/files from your repository ?

The act of securely copying files from your repository to the runner is called as checking. This is an essential step & is often a primary step (done first). That's why in any CI/CD pipeline, you see that in the first few lines, they checkout the repository.

More info on GitHub runners is available [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners).